# Magento 2 - How To Display Cross Sell Products Against Each Line In Basket

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, cross-sells

I am looking to try and add **Cross-Sell products** against the specific product they are related to.

I understand that currently, the cross-sell products are shown on the cart page in relation to every product in the cart.

I would like it to be the following format:

> - Product Added To Cart 1
> - [Cross Sell For Product 1][Cross Sell For Product 1][Cross Sell For Product 1]
> - Product Added To Cart 2
> - [Cross Sell For Product 2][Cross Sell For Product 2][Cross Sell For Product 2]

This would ensure that a customer who buys an Oak Dining Table Can be prompted to buy matching Oak seats, side table, and TV cabinet. On the line below maybe they purchased some Flowers and need to be reminded that they should buy a vase, fertilizer, and watering can.

Many Thanks